# Android Resource not found exception when trying to add a datepicker to layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-datepicker

All I'm trying to do is simply add a date picker to a linear layout with API level 21. When I'm doing that I get for some reason `Resources$NotFoundException`

This is the exception's trace:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:490)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.obtainStyledAttributes(BridgeContext.java:93)
    at android.widget.TextView.setTextAppearance(TextView.java:2484)
    at android.widget.YearPickerView$YearAdapter.getView(YearPickerView.java:132)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:626)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:526)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onXmlModelChanged(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1267)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateXmlModelChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:402)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.xmlModelChanged(CommonXmlEditor.java:329)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1653)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1114)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.wrapUndoEditXmlModel(AndroidXmlEditor.java:1190)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.OutlineDropListener.performDrop(OutlineDropListener.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerDropAdapter.drop(ViewerDropAdapter.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(DNDListener.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(DropTarget.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(DropTarget.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(COMObject.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM.DoDragDrop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.drag(DragSource.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource.access$0(DragSource.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DragSource$1.handleEvent(DragSource.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

I have tried to clean the project and delete the R file. I have read that other people had this issue because they had somewhere in their code a call to `txtview.settext()` with an `int` parameter but I checked my code and each place get a string.

Why can't I add the wiget to the layout?

Comment: show your xml file...

Comment: is this error from logcat? mobile? if yes then why do you have a `org.eclipse....` in error stack? if not, i think it's some eclipse problem try t restart eclipse

Comment: xml of what? I'm simply dragging a datepicker in the Eclipse's graphical layout manager to a linear layout of an already existing layout. there's nothing there besides a textview and a fragment inside a liner layout.

Comment: @Yazan I copied the above trace from Eclipse's Error Log. It's not a runtime exception - it happens right after I simply drag the widget to the layout

Comment: @YonatanNir i think it's some theme issue, rendering version vs theme selected for app, i mean when eclipse try to render the view based on target SDK, and app theme, it might be unsupported. maybe ... i am not sure

Comment: Do you might know how can I check if there's some SDK version issue like you said? With WPF it wouldn't have happened...

Comment: @YonatanNir i am not sure, can you tell what theme is used in application tag at manifest? `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` is it like this or other theme name like holo...

Comment: It's the AppTheme as you wrote. I didn't define any new styles at all for this app.

Comment: @YonatanNir i am sorry, i am not sure what is the reason, just add eclipse tag to ur question you may get better help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue until I put in the DatePicker:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
```